# Display settings in Awesome WM are missing

Tags: linux, gnome, awesome-wm

I'm trying to start using awesome WM on my dell xps laptop (+ external display) running pop os, but I'm having trouble with the display settings: they are not shown.

[image]

I opened these settings from the terminal with `gnome-control-center`. In the terminal, the following (possibly related) output is shown:

```
(gnome-control-center:9019): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:38:46.671: Missing property 'ApplyMonitorsConfigAllowed' on DisplayConfig API

(gnome-control-center:9019): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 17:38:46.671: Error calling GetCurrentState: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Destination does not exist
```

I've googled a but couldn't find any useful results. It doesn't help that I'm really quite confused by the terminology (Wayland, Xorg, X11, xrandr, arandr, ...)

When logging in to the popos window manager, the settings *are* shown correctly:

[image]

---

**edit**

I am starting to think these settings are not applying to awesomeWM at all. I tried changing an unrelated setting (scrolling: 'natural'), in the same settings panel, and nothing changed. (I also tried restarting awesome.)

**Is it possible, the incorrect settings panel is being loaded? Or is that the settings are correct, but not picked up by awesome?**

Comment: How are you running POP OS on your laptop?

Comment: How? I've installed it a year or so ago. It's the only OS on the device, and it now has 2 window managers for me to choose from when logging in: "awesome" and "pop". Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Hmmmm... Noone?